# 正規表現でマッチしない場合には元の文字列にマッチさせたい

Tags: python, 正規表現

正規表現で特定文字列より前にマッチさせたいのですが、
その特定文字列が含まれない場合には、元の文字列にマッチさせるようにするには
どうすればよいでしょうか。

抽出したい内容：
"aaa"または"bbb"が対象に含まれる場合には、その前までの文字列、
含まれない場合には元の文字列、にマッチさせたいです。

やってみた正規表現：

```
"(.*?)(aaa|bbb).*"
```

これだと"aaa"または"bbb"を含む場合にはその前の文字列にマッチしますが、
"aaa"や"bbb"にもマッチしてしまうのと、
"aaa"や"bbb"を含まない場合には何にもマッチしません。

Comment: 「元の文字列」と言うのがよく分からないのですが、「比較対象の文字列全体」と言う意味でしょうか? また一口に正規表現と言っても環境によって使える機能などに差異があるのですが、どのような環境の正規表現でしょうか?

Comment: Regex engine が PCRE(Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) だとすれば、肯定的先読みを使って `(^(.*?)(?=(aaa|bbb))|^.*$)` など。

Comment: できれば想定している対象の "文字列" と、結果を何例か示してあると回答する人にもイメージが伝わりやすいです。 / やろうとしていることは正規表現を使った **置換** のような気もします。

Comment: 質問は`(aaa|bbb).*`にマッチする文字列を削除(空文字に置換)するだけでよいように読み取れます。

Comment: 環境はpythonのreモジュールですが、正規表現自体はソースの外出しになります。やろうとしていることは、終了文字パターンの前までの文字を切り出すことですが、その終了文字が含まれるとは限らないため、含まれない場合には文字列全体にマッチさせたいです。

Answer (score 2):

**回答**
`re.sub`で終了文字列パターン以降を空文字列に置換したものが抽出結果です。
終了文字列パターンにマッチした文字列だけが削除(空文字列で置換)されますので、マッチしなければ元の文字列が得られます。

**コード**

```py
def extract(str, patern):
    import re
    return re.sub(patern, "", str)
```

**呼び出しコード**

```
終了文字列パターン = "(aaa|bbb).*"
対象文字列1 = "AAAaaaZZZ"
対象文字列2 = "AAAbbbZZZ"
対象文字列3 = "AAAcccZZZ"
print("対象文字列1=[" + str(対象文字列1) + "]")
print("対象文字列2=[" + str(対象文字列2) + "]")
print("対象文字列3=[" + str(対象文字列3) + "]")

結果1 = extract(対象文字列1, 終了文字列パターン)
print("結果1=[" + str(結果1) + "]")

結果2 = extract(対象文字列2, 終了文字列パターン)
print("結果2=[" + str(結果2) + "]")

結果3 = extract(対象文字列3, 終了文字列パターン)
print("結果3=[" + str(結果3) + "]")
```

**結果**

```
終了文字列パターン=[(aaa|bbb).*]
対象文字列1=[AAAaaaZZZ]
対象文字列2=[AAAbbbZZZ]
対象文字列3=[AAAcccZZZ]
結果1=[AAA]
結果2=[AAA]
結果3=[AAAcccZZZ]
```

Answer (score 2):

コードの方をいじれるんなら、akira ejiriさんの回答で十分だと思います。

こちらは、コメントに「正規表現自体はソースの外出し」と言うことですので、使う正規表現によって、コードの方をいじったりはできず、正規表現のマッチする範囲自体が切り出したい文字列になっていないといけない、と言う想定での回答になります。

```
import re

a = "AAAaaaZZZ"
b = "AAAbbbZZZ"
c = "AAAcccZZZ"

pattern = "(.*?)(?=aaa|bbb|$)"

print(re.match(pattern, a).group(0))
print(re.match(pattern, b).group(0))
print(re.match(pattern, c).group(0))
```

実行例

```
AAA
AAA
AAAcccZZZ
```

---

マッチに使用しているコードによっては、若干書き換える必要があるかもしれませんが、

- "aaa"や"bbb"にもマッチしてしまう

  →(metropolisさんのコメントにあるように)肯定的先読み`(?=〜)`が使える
- "aaa"や"bbb"を含まない場合には何にもマッチしません

  →対象の"aaa"、"bbb"に加え、終端を表す`$`を同じ並びに入れてやる

と言う形で解決しています。